# Declare type with single required property and unbounded additional properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to declare a function that takes an argument which has a type defined as an object with a single required property and any number of additional properties open format (`T`) while requiring the additional properties to adhere to the type signature of `T`.  Specifically I'm trying to do something like this:

```
export myFunc<T>(props: { 
  data: {
    key: string;
    [x: T]: any;
  }[]
}) { // myFunc code... }
```

The above definitely doesn't work.  I've tried the approach using `[x: string]: any;` but that is too permissive and allows deviation from the type signature for `T`.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't currently have great support for the type you're talking about.  The problem is that if an index signature exists, all named properties corresponding to the index signature must be compatible with it.  Assuming that `string` is not assignable to `T`, the type `{key: string, [k: string]: T}` won't work.  This restriction kind of makes sense, but it has been a source of frustration sometimes.

Maybe in the foreseeable future it will be possible to use [arbitrary index signature types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) and [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317); if so, you could likely express the type as something like `{key: string; [K: string & not "key"]: T}`.  That is, you will be able to explicitly exclude `"key"` from the index signature.  But we're not there yet.

One thing you can do is use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) like `{key: string} & {[k: string]: T}` to circumvent the issue.  But this doesn't work in some cases, especially yours, where you are likely to pass in an object literal:

```
declare function myFunc<T>(props: {
  data: Array<{
    key: string
  } & { [x: string]: T }>
}): void;

myFunc<number>({ data: [{ key: "a" }] }); // error!
//                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- key is incompatible with index signature
```

The other workaround is to make the `myFunc` a generic function that infers the type of the `props` parameter as generic type `P`, and then uses a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type to verify that `P` meets your requirement.  It's very long and messy and actually requires me to make it a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function to allow you to manually specify `T` but then have the compiler infer `P` (the consequence of another currently [missing feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) in TypeScript):

```
type EnsureProps<
  P extends { data: Array<{ key: string }> },
  T,
  A extends any[] = P['data']
  > = {
    data: {
      [I in keyof A]: {
        [K in keyof A[I]]?: K extends 'key' ? string : T
      }
    }
  };

declare const myFuncMaker: <T>() =>
  <P extends {
    data: Array<{ key: string }>
  }>(props: P & EnsureProps<P, T>) =>
    void;
```

But at least it does work:

```
const myFunc = myFuncMaker<number>();

myFunc({ data: [{ key: "a", dog: 1, cat: "2" }] }); // error!
//                                  ~~~ <-- string is not assignable to never

myFunc({ data: [{ key: "a", dog: 1 }, { key: "b", cat: 4 }] }); // okay
```

---

So let's step back.  All of that is either unworkable, problematic, or a nightmare of type jugging.  The compiler really doesn't want to let you represent this type.    I'd probably suggest that you think about refactoring the `myFunc()` function so that the parameters are more amenable to TypeScript's type system.  For example, if you push the additional properties of type `T` down one level but leave the `"key"` where it is, it would work well:

```
declare function myFunc<T>(props: {
  data: Array<{
    key: string,
    more?: { [x: string]: T };
  }>
}): void;

myFunc<number>({ data: [{ key: "a", more: { a: 1, b: 2 } }] });
```

I can see how that's a bit less convenient for you, but it might be worth it to save yourself the headache of having the compiler fighting against you.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: This lays out the problem really well-- thanks for breaking it down so thoroughly!